# Running Jquery within Angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an Angular app that that multiple tabs. I am using angular-ui-router.min.js to help with some additional routing.

Within my global controller I have embedded a jQuery function that does not load unless I start it with:

```
$(window).load(function () { // something });
```

This contents of the function requires that the DOM is loaded as it's looking for classes and IDs to do its thing. Even then it only works when I refresh the page. If I am switching between tabs then this function isn't called at all.

Should I be separating my jQuery from my Angular controllers - it does feel a bit wrong that I have some DOM fiddling functions within controllers as that does goes against Angulars approach altogether.

Comment: Is the function code you own or a third-party lib? You will wan't to remove this from the controller -- depending on what it is, it should be moved to a directive, service or wrapped in a service.

Comment: The function is a third-party library, using Highcharts within an AngularJS app.

Comment: So you would probably want to wrap highcharts in a directive. Luckily this has already been done: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng and http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=highcharts